# LAN9512 keeps disconnecting from RPi Compute Module

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, ethernet

### Main problem

I'm using a [RPi CM](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/datasheets/rpi_DATA_CM_1p0.pdf) and I connected a [LAN9512](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002304A.pdf) to it.
However it keeps disconnecting:

```
usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
```

### Power rails

- 18.0V
- 5.0V (generated from 18.0V)
- 4.1V (generated from 18.0V)
- 3.3V (generated from 5.0V)
- 2.5V (generated from 3.3V)
- 1.8V (generated from 5.0V)

All powers are generated by [MP2359](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/277/MP2359_r1.21-477634.pdf).
This SMPS is able to power consumers up to 1.2A so it should be enough for the RPi CM.

RPi CM needs 3.3V and 1.8V, LAN9512 needs 3.3V.

### LAN9512's layout

[image: LAN9512's layout]

Note: its ETH and USB lines are routed in differantial mode:

- ETH TX: 65.655mm length, 100% matched.
- ETH RX: 62.341mm length, 100% matched.
- USB: 41.545mm length, 99.7% matched.

This is a 4-layer PCB, and USB lines are wired on the 3rd plane. 2nd plane is GND, so as the 4th one.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the power rails with a scope? Do you have enough capacitance on the rails to be able to compensate for any possible peaks in load?

Comment: Do you have pull-up resistors on the USB lines?

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat rails on scope shows nothing special or interesting figure. How can I check the capacitance of the rail? I have 22uF inductors on every SMPS output. Is that good enough?

Comment: @Oldfart No! I don't have any pull-up on USB lines. Should I have them? What is the recommended value? BTW, original Rpi is also not having them: https://elinux.org/images/3/32/Schematics-diff-page3.png, thanks!

Comment: I did not know that, I was convinced you needed resistors. AH found it! LAN9512 has  Integrated USB termination Pull-up/Pull-down 
resistors. So forget about my question. (It was a long shot anyway).